# Can I legally work online for a Canadian company, as a Canadian citizen living in the US?

Tags: employment

I am a Canadian citizen living in the United States.  I do not have a visa to work here, I am here on an H4 visa, which is the spouse visa for my husband's H4 work visa. I would like to be able to teach online for a Canadian company while living here in the US, but am not sure if it is legal to do so or not.  And would I need some kind of US work permit or visa?  And how would I pay income taxes - I'm assuming Canadian income taxes?  Any information someone could share would be helpful.  I have searched extensively online and am not finding any answers.

Comment: We have another site called [expatriates.se] which specifically deals with living and working abroad, especially visa questions, and would likely be able to answer this.